# Getting large cryptic errors and warnings when trying to use mongoose with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, webpack

I'm using webpack to compile my es6 isomorphic react application into client and server bundles, respectively.  I've installed mongoose and are attempting to use it in the server portion of my app, but I'm getting some horrendous errors in the console when I try building:

> WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js Critical dependencies:
>   8:11-74 the request of a dependency is an expression  @
>   ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js 8:11-74
>
> WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/SPEC.md Module parse failed:
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/SPEC.md
>   Line 2: Unexpected token ILLEGAL You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. | | # Driver Spec | | TODO  @
>   ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers ^./.*$
>
> WARNING in ./~/express/lib/view.js Critical dependencies: 78:29-56 the
>   request of a dependency is an expression  @ ./~/express/lib/view.js
>   78:29-56
>
> WARNING in ./~/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js Module not found:
>   Error: Cannot resolve module 'vertx' in
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/es6-promise/dist
>   resolve module vertx in
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/es6-promise/dist
>   looking for modules in
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src
>       /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src/vertx doesn't exist (module as directory)
>       resolve 'file' vertx in /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src
>         resolve file
>           /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src/vertx doesn't exist
>           /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src/vertx.js
>   doesn't exist   looking for modules in
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules
>       /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/vertx
>   doesn't exist (module as directory)
>       resolve 'file' vertx in /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules
>         resolve file
>           /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/vertx
>   doesn't exist
>           /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/vertx.js
>   doesn't exist
>   [/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src/vertx]
>   [/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src/vertx]
>   [/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/src/vertx.js]
>   [/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/vertx]
>   [/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/vertx]
>   [/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/vertx.js]
>   @ ./~/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js 132:20-30
>
> WARNING in ./~/bson/lib/bson/index.js Critical dependencies: 20:16-29
>   the request of a dependency is an expression 44:18-31 the request of a
>   dependency is an expression 71:19-32 the request of a dependency is an
>   expression  @ ./~/bson/lib/bson/index.js 20:16-29 44:18-31 71:19-32
>
> WARNING in ./~/require_optional/index.js Critical dependencies:
>   63:18-42 the request of a dependency is an expression 71:20-44 the
>   request of a dependency is an expression 78:35-67 the request of a
>   dependency is an expression  @ ./~/require_optional/index.js 63:18-42
>   71:20-44 78:35-67
>
> WARNING in ./~/require_optional/README.md Module parse failed:
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/require_optional/README.md
>   Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. | # require_optional | Work around the problem
>   that we do not have a optionalPeerDependencies concept in node.js
>   making it a hassle to optionally include native modules |  @
>   ./~/require_optional ^./.*$
>
> WARNING in ./~/require_optional/LICENSE Module parse failed:
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/node_modules/require_optional/LICENSE
>   Line 1: Unexpected identifier You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. |                                  Apache
>   License |                            Version 2.0, January 2004 |
>   http://www.apache.org/licenses/  @ ./~/require_optional ^./.*$
>   /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:235900
>         return map[req] || (function() { throw new Error("Cannot find module
>   '" + req + "'.") }());
>                                          ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './node-mongodb-native'.
>       at /Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:235900:42
>       at webpackContextResolve (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:235900:90)
>       at webpackContext (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:235897:30)
>       at Object. (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:48684:37)
>       at **webpack_require** (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:52685:17)
>       at **webpack_require** (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:20:30)
>       at Object. (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:236259:15)
>       at **webpack_require** (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:20:30)
>       at Object.exports.contain.exports.reachTemplate.internals.Any.applyFunctionToChildren.internals.Err.toString.internals.getPath.internals.serializer.internals.annotate.internals.Response._prepare.internals.Response._processPrepare.internals.Auth.test.internals.Auth.payload.internals.Auth.response.internals.Authenticator.exports.wrap.internals.isIsoDate.internals.compare.internals.Date.min.internals.Date.max.internals.Connection._init.internals.Connection._start.internals.Connection._stop.internals.Connection._dispatch.internals.Methods._add.internals.state.internals.payload.internals.compare.internals.Number.min.internals.Number.max.internals.Number.greater.internals.Number.less.internals.Number.multiple.internals.Number.integer.internals.Number.negative.internals.Number.positive.internals.Object.length.internals.Object.min.internals.Object.max.internals.Object.assert.internals.compare.internals.String.min.internals.String.max.internals.String.creditCard.internals.String.length.internals.String.regex.internals.String.alphanum.internals.String.token.internals.String.email.internals.String.ip.internals.String.uri.internals.String.isoDate.internals.String.guid.internals.String.hex.internals.String.hostname.internals.String.lowercase.internals.String.uppercase.internals.Request.internals.Response.writeHead.internals.Topo.add.exports.execute.internals.prerequisites.internals.handler.internals.fromString.internals.pre.module.exports.internals.Plugin.internals.Plugin.register.internals.Protect.run.internals.Request.internals.Request._execute.internals.Request._lifecycle.internals.Request._invoke.internals.Server.start.internals.Server.initialize.internals.Server._start.internals.Server.stop._invoke.exports.send.internals.marshal.internals.fail.internals.transmit.internals.state.internals.input.exports.response.internals.Router.normalize.internals.parseParams.internals.Router.table.internals.Policy.get.internals.Policy._callGenerateFunc.internals.Policy.set.exports.generateKey.exports.encrypt.exports.decrypt.exports.hmacWithPassword.exports.seal.exports.unseal.internals.Array.items.internals.Array.ordered.internals.Array.min.internals.Array.max.internals.Array.length.internals.Binary.min.internals.Binary.max.internals.checkIpV6.exports.validate.internals.validate.internals.Definitions.parse.Items.serial.internals.unsign.Items.serial.internals.unsign.internals.decode.internals.Definitions.format.Items.serial.exports.prepareValue.internals.encode.internals.sign.internals.Parser.internals.Parser.parse.decoder.once.writeFile.internals.Parser.raw.decoder.once.internals.Parser.multipart.onPart.writeFile.exports.Dispenser.internals.Dispenser.internals.Client.request.internals.Client.read.internals.Client.parseCacheControl.internals.Client._shortcut.map../connection
>   (/Users/richie/Code/CreativeFlumeProjects/cf-website/public/server.bundle.js:235702:19)

I've tried a number of solutions found through google.  Adding ".node" to my resolve.extensions, adding node-loader, as well as some additional configurations to the node object, all to no avail.

Comment: Try to exclude `node_modules` from js loader and set `target: "node"` in server-side config.

Comment: Mind sharing your config please?

Answer (score 21):

Your webpack config that handles the server code should have a few extras to avoid issues.

Try adding the following:

```
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        ...,
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    },
    externals: [
        /^(?!\.|\/).+/i,
    ],
```

Setting the `target` to `node` makes webpack aware that you're working in a Node context, and not in a browser. Adding `libraryTarget: 'commonjs'` will make webpack use simple `require` calls to get functions from external libraries.

Then an important thing happens in the regex in `externals`. It basically excludes any requires that use a non-relative path from the bundle. That way if you do `import 'react';` it won't be packaged by webpack, but if you do `import './components/MyComponent.js';`, it will.

That will also mean that you have to make sure your `node_modules` directory is included with your built server code.

Why do all this? Because Node uses a lot of native modules that can't be bundled right. They are specific to your exact version of Node on your specific OS, and you can't just pull those into a Javascript bundle. You want your own code to go through webpack, and all stuff from `node_modules` to just be accessed like any Node project.

Now if you get those warnings/errors in your browser bundle, it means that you're probably requiring/importing modules that only work on the server in your browser bundle. Make sure you only require them in files that are only used on the server. Alternatively, selectively require them. How you can do selective requires based on the build type can be found here: [Can I detect if my script is being processed by Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217165/can-i-detect-if-my-script-is-being-processed-by-webpack/32223424#32223424)

Comment: It works, but break the resolve root path. How can i handle the resolve root path?

Comment: If you add things to the resolve root for easier requires you need to adjust the externals regex to not match your internal modules, or use an alternative strategy. A common one is scanning the node_modules directory for packages and marking those as external, you can use this package for that instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals

Comment: Would it be enough just to add "mongoose" as external?

Comment: @JuanJeGarcía, yes, but you'd have to do that for every single dependency you use. Some dependencies might seem to bundle just fine, but might fail at runtime. If you're using webpack to bundle Node-code, I'd highly recommend to use the regex in my answers instead.

Comment: Great answer. Solved lots of hairyness. Thanks

Comment: Good answer dude! Solved my 2 hour struggle, I was missing externals.