# Cannot find module './node-mongodb-native' when using webpack with mongoose

Tags: webpack

I have created a simple repro for this problem. Attached as zip.

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/code-public/mongoose-webpack.zip

The main problem seems to be the bundled javascript contains

map = {
./node-mongodb-native/binary:118
./node-mongodb-native/binary.js:118
./node-mongodb-native/collection:119
./node-mongodb-native/collection.js:119
./node-mongodb-native/connection:209
./node-mongodb-native/connection.js:209
./node-mongodb-native/index:215
./node-mongodb-native/index.js:215
./node-mongodb-native/objectid:216
./node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:216
./node-mongodb-native/ReadPreference:33
./node-mongodb-native/ReadPreference.js:33
./SPEC.md:6
}

but does not contain an entry that is just ./node-mongodb-native, so when they do a map loopup map['./node-mongodb-native'] it finds nothing so we get an error.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107800/getting-large-cryptic-errors-and-warnings-when-trying-to-use-mongoose-with-webpa . Maybe going through that helps.