# Trying to use mongoose in nodejs app using Webpack as module Bundler

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webpack

I am trying to integrate mongoDB in my nodejs-react application. I'm using mongoose as orm.
It started with the folowing errors

```
WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./win32/x64/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 6:10-37
```

I came across as similar question on stackoverflow, and made the required changes in my webpack config file

- Added node and json loader.

  { test: /.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },

  {
                  test: /.node$/,
                  loader: 'node-loader'
  }
- Added resolve and node object.

  resolve: {

  extensions: [ '', '.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.es6', '.babel', '.node'],

  modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules', 'app' ]
  },

  node: {

  console: true,

  fs: 'empty',

  net: 'empty',

  tls: 'empty'
  },

npm install json-loader
npm install node-loader

Here's how my webpack config file looks like now.

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

var assetPath = '/assets/'
var absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, 'build', assetPath)

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'node-webkit',
  output: {
    path: absolutePath,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: assetPath
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("bundle.css")
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [ 'babel' ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
      // fonts and svg
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      {
        // images
        test: /\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        loader: "file"
      },
      {
        // for some modules like foundation
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/], // sassLoader will include node_modules explicitly
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!postcss!sass?outputStyle=expanded")
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!postcss")
      },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      {
                test: /\.node$/,
                loader: 'node-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
      extensions: [ '', '.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.es6', '.babel', '.node'],
      modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules', 'app' ]
  },
  node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  },
  postcss: function(webpack) {
    return [
      autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 9', 'and_chr >= 2.3']})
    ]
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")]
  }
}
```

All the errors are gone but i’m still getting the following warnings and bundle is not getting generated.

```
WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./win32/ia32/bson in /Users/Johannes/Documents/Development/holmes/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/bson/~/bson-ext/ext/index.js 8:10-38



  WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js
    Critical dependencies:
    8:11-74 the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/index.js 8:11-74


WARNING in ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers/SPEC.md
Module parse failed: /Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/SPEC.md Unexpected character '#' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (2:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:920:13)
    at Parser.pp.getTokenFromCode (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2813:8)
    at Parser.pp.readToken (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2508:15)
    at Parser.pp.nextToken (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2500:71)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1615:10)
    at Object.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:882:44)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
 @ ./~/mongoose/lib/drivers ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'vertx' in /Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/es6-promise/dist
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js 132:20-30

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/bson/lib/bson/index.js
Critical dependencies:
20:16-29 the request of a dependency is an expression
44:18-31 the request of a dependency is an expression
71:19-32 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/bson/lib/bson/index.js 20:16-29 44:18-31 71:19-32

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/require_optional/index.js
Critical dependencies:
63:18-42 the request of a dependency is an expression
71:20-44 the request of a dependency is an expression
78:35-67 the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/require_optional/index.js 63:18-42 71:20-44 78:35-67

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/require_optional/LICENSE
Module parse failed: /Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/require_optional/LICENSE Unexpected token (1:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:40)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:920:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1483:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1462:73)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1976:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1754:188)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1648:21)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1616:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:882:44)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/require_optional ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/require_optional/README.md
Module parse failed: /Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/require_optional/README.md Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:920:13)
    at Parser.pp.getTokenFromCode (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2813:8)
    at Parser.pp.readToken (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2508:15)
    at Parser.pp.nextToken (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2500:71)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1615:10)
    at Object.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:882:44)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/nitesh/Documents/learnReact/day1/r3-foundation-boilerplate/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
 @ ./~/mongoose/~/mongodb/~/mongodb-core/~/require_optional ^\.\/.*$
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 221 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles/app.css 219 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 8.56 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles/styles.css 7.06 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 7.92 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles/slider.css 6.42 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 234 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles/app_override.css 232 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
                                     Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
      404a525502f8e5ba7e93b9f02d9e83a9.eot  75.2 kB               
    926c93d201fe51c8f351e858468980c3.woff2  70.7 kB               
     891e3f340c1126b4c7c142e5f6e86816.woff  89.1 kB               
      fb650aaf10736ffb9c4173079616bf01.ttf   151 kB               
      bae4a87c1e5dff40baa3f49d52f5347a.svg   386 kB               
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 41.4 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles/index.css 264 bytes {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
        [2] ./~/css-loader!./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css 39.1 kB {0} [built]
        [3] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot 82 bytes {0} [built]
        [4] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.1 82 bytes {0} [built]
        [5] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.1 84 bytes {0} [built]
        [6] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.1 83 bytes {0} [built]
        [7] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.1 82 bytes {0} [built]
        [8] ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.1 82 bytes {0} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 88.8 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded!./src/styles/foundation.scss 87.3 kB {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting large cryptic errors and warnings when trying to use mongoose with webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107800/getting-large-cryptic-errors-and-warnings-when-trying-to-use-mongoose-with-webpa)