# Could not resolve module 'fs' webpack

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, chai, supertest, karma-mocha

I am trying to unit test my code. I need to test an api call that has a relative url. Am trying to use supertest for api mocks.

Here's a snippet of my test code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const supertest = require('supertest');

app.use(express.bodyParser());

it('should get required details', (done) => {
      supertest(app)
      .get('/home/api/getdetails')
      .expect(200, { response: { foo: 'bar', done);

      const expectedActions = [{ type: 'DETAILS',
        payload: { foo: 'bar' } }];
      const store = mockStore({}, expectedActions);
      const func = getDetails();
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log("func"+func);
      const dispatch = sinon.spy();
      func(dispatch);
      expect(store.getActions()).
          to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
    });
```

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var env = require('./env');

// List of allowed environments
var allowedEnvs = ['env1', 'env2', 'env3', 'env4', 'env5', 'env6', 'env7', 'env7'];

// Get available configurations
var configs = {
  env0: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env0')),
  env1: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env1')),
  env2: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env2')),
  env3: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env3')),
  env4: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env4')),
  env5: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env5')),
  env6: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env6')),
  env7: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env7')),
  env8: require(path.join(__dirname, 'cfg/env8')),
};

/**
 * Get an allowed environment
 * @param  {String}  env
 * @return {String}
 */
function getValidEnv(env) {
  var isValid = env && env.length > 0 && allowedEnvs.indexOf(env) !== -1;
  return isValid ? env : 'dev';
}

/**
 * Build the webpack configuration
 * @param  {String} env Environment to use
 * @return {Object} Webpack config
 */
function buildConfig(env) {
  var usedEnv = getValidEnv(env);
  return configs[usedEnv];
}

module.exports = buildConfig(env);
```

Everywhere, it is said that just by adding,

```
node:{
 fs: 'empty',
}
```

would solve the issue. But, the issue is not resolved for me.
Could anyone please help me with this?

Thank you,
Aswini J

Comment: I couldn't find any solution till now. It would be really helpful if any of you could help me solve this. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use webpack for code that will be executed in Node? If yes, you need a few special things to webpack Node code. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36132615/1366795